# Proper way of adding CGAL points api-wise

Tags: cgal

I have a triangle defined by its three vertices. The vertices are of type `Point = CGAL::Point_2<K>` with a `Simple_cartersian<double>` kernel.

I want to randomly sample this triangle and for that I use a formula (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18686/uniform-random-point-in-triangle-in-3d) which adds the three vertices of the triangle multiplied by some random factors.

```
                Point = Point(0, 0) +                                                //
                        (1 - std::sqrt(r1)) * (standardTriangle[0] - Point(0, 0)) +  //
                        (std::sqrt(r1) * (1 - r2)) * (standardTriangle[1] - Point(0, 0)) +
                        (r2 * std::sqrt(r1)) * (standardTriangle[2] - Point(0, 0)));
```

This looks very cumbersome, as I need to convert the points to vector by substracting Point(0,0)  and then I need to add everything to a Point on the origin.

Looks more natural to just do something like the following

```
                Point = (1 - std::sqrt(r1)) * standardTriangle[0] +  //
                        (std::sqrt(r1) * (1 - r2)) * standardTriangle[1] +
                        (r2 * std::sqrt(r1)) * standardTriangle[2]);
```

Adding and removing points from the origin is really the only way to sum points, even though mathematically this is not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the [`barycenter()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/group__barycenter__grp.html#ga2cb3731a1798367ccdab76efc3578bde) function.

In case you need another sampling there is one available in CGAL. See [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Generator/classCGAL_1_1Random__points__in__triangle__3.html)

Comment: Although I appreaciate pointing to functions which sample a triangle, my question is not about how to sample a triangle, but about the extra steps and operations needed to sum two points.

Comment: Reading again my answer I start by providing you the link to the `barycenter` function that can be used for computing weighting sum of points so I don't understand what you are looking for then.

Comment: What if I want to sum 7 points? I am asking if there is an easy way to perform the sum of points instead of needing to convert all the points to vector by substracting CGAL::Origin or Point(0,0)

Comment: You cannot add points directly because as you pointed out it is not mathematically correct. You can do linear combination of the Cartesian coordinates if you need to operate on more that 4 points.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Mathematical consistency makes sense for such a complex library.

Comment: If you point the linear combination tip in the answer, Ill mark it as accepted